# How to create html menu based on database table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have table category

[image]

how to create second level menu where  `rodzic != 0` (rodzic means parent)

- Kominki na drewno

  - Atra
  - Jotul
  - Scan
- Kratki kominowe
- Wkłady kominowe
- Kominki gazowe

Comment: In what format have you retrieved the data from the database? Do you simply want a HTML [`<ul>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) list as a menu?

Comment: Exacly I need HTML `<ul> <li>` list

Comment: It's easy when you have your rows in a PHP array. While iterating, you can check for `rodzic!=0` and just `echo` your `nazwa` wrapped in `<li>` elements. Perhaps you should provide some of that part of your code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have data in an array like this:

```
$data = [
    ['id' => 3, 'typ' => 'kategorie', 'rodzic' => 0, 'nazwa' => 'OFERTA'],
    ['id' => 5, 'typ' => 'kategorie', 'rodzic' => 3, 'nazwa' => 'Kominki na drewno'],
    /* more elements here */
];
```

You can first process the array and get two arrays out of it: array of top level elements and an array of sub-elements:

```
$top_level = [];
$sub_elem = [];

foreach($data as $row) {
    $rd = $row['rodzic'];
    if($rd) { // has parent
        if(!isset($sub_elem[$rd])) { // first time encounter, initialize array
            $sub_elem[$rd] = [];
        }

        $sub_elem[$rd][] = $row; // append row
    }
    else {
        $top_level[] = $row; // append top level row
    }
}
```

Then you just iterate over the data like this:

```
<ul>
<?php foreach($top_level as $row): ?>
    <li>
        <?php echo $row['nazwa'] ?>
        <?php if(isset($sub_elem[$row['id']])): ?>
        <ul>
            <?php foreach($sub_elem[$row['id']] as $sub_row): ?>
                <li><?php echo $sub_row['nazwa'] ?></li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
    </li>
<?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

This will only work for a depth of one. To have arbitrary nesting of lists, you need to make a [recursive](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/recursion/info) function, which I'll leave as an exercise for the reader.